# Spring - What changed from 4.2.0.RELEASE to 4.3.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I was using spring `<springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>` then everything was working fine, but when I update to `<springframework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>` I saw my code started giving errors for imports. Please let me know what has changed in `4.2.0.RELEASE` to `4.3.5.RELEASE`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing changed that would cause those errors. Seems like your IDE is having trouble, so try resetting/refreshing it and/or your local maven cache.

Comment: If you use maven try to update maven project configuration in your IDE